# How to connect custom stm32 board to debugger

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, stm32f4, st-link, openocd

I have a custom STM32 microcontroller board. I have verified all of the electrical connections, and I am able to program the board with Texane's st-flash utility. However, I would like to debug the board as well, and I am having trouble doing this. I am using Visual Studio Code with cortex-debug extension. The extension (I haven't used the command line utility for debugging much, not sure if it has the same requirements) requires that I have the SVD file for the specific chip - something I was unable to find online. The chip is the STM32F439ZIT6. For other boards, including the F407 discovery, I have not had any issues programming or debugging the board, but I also already have the SVD files for those chips that I found online. So, my question is where can I find the SVD files? Or how do I make them?

Alternatively, I looked a bit into using OpenOCD to debug - however I have been unsuccessful in getting that working at all. The most success I've had is running

```
openocd -f interface/stlink-v2-1.cfg -f target/stm32f4x.cfg
```

but this hits the error:

```
Info : auto-selecting first available session transport "hla_swd". To override use 'transport select <transport>'.
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
adapter speed: 2000 kHz
adapter_nsrst_delay: 100
none separate
Info : Unable to match requested speed 2000 kHz, using 1800 kHz
Info : Unable to match requested speed 2000 kHz, using 1800 kHz
Info : clock speed 1800 kHz
Error: open failed
in procedure 'init' 
in procedure 'ocd_bouncer'
```

I think OpenOCD might be more powerful and something useful to learn, but from what I've found, there aren't many resources for using it with the ST-Link programmers and a custom board.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Try these files, first match on google:

Comment: https://github.com/posborne/cmsis-svd/tree/master/data/STMicro

Comment: @A.R.C. I saw those files, but there isn't one for the STM32F439, unfortunately

Comment: Check out if there is a similar device listed. They are compatible most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try the SVD file for `STM32F429`, as they are almost identical to the `STM32F439`, the only difference is that `STM32F429` lacks the AES encryption module.

Looking into the `STM32F429.svd` files found on the net, they include definitions for the encryption module as well, so they are apparently for both MCUs.

Comment: I'll go ahead and give that a try. Also, what information does the SVD file contain? Register definitions?

Answer (score 1):

Check your board again, sometimes you can't image how funny u are.

And Try this shell when use ST-LINK SWD mode:

openocd_stlink.cfg:
`source [find interface/stlink-v2-1.cfg
transport select swd
source [find target/stm32f4x.cfg]`

then run openocd in shell:

`openocd -f ./openocd_stlink.cfg`

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go. However, I am using JTAG, not SWD